# iPhone - Showing the road speed limit while driving

Tags: ios, software-recommendation

I am looking for an iOS application that can display the speed limit of the road where I am located. I am mostly interested in the USA, particularly Boston and California. Gratis is better but not necessary.

Comment: Here in CA if they catch you looking at your iPhone screen while driving it is $300 :)

Comment: Do they still also have that silly rule whereby you're allowed to have a sat nav, but can't stick it to your windscreen & instead have to sit it on some kind of bean-bag that falls off the dash every time you go round a corner - which of course is *far* less distracting than just sticking it to the screen in the first place? :P

Comment: [Navfree](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/navfree-gps-usa-+-street-view/id405922167?mt=8) though apparently it doesn't have all speed limits, depends on the underlying open streetmap

Answer (score 4):

In the latest version of iOS 11, I believe the speed limit does show up on highways (at least when you're going too fast). Another app that does this is Waze.

Answer (score 3):

[HERE WeGo](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/here-wego/id955837609) maps app (formerly Nokia Here Maps) for iOS has **exactly** the functionality you are looking for.

The app can be downloaded for **free** on the App Store (all features available, no In-App purchases).

The app features **excellent** and **extensive** maps data, with **full offline support**. You can easily search for points of interest and perform navigation even without a data connection (Solely with the help of GPS).

The maps data is regularly updated and you can choose to download maps on a country/province basis.

[image]

As can be seen in the screenshot, the app not only contains up-to-date speed limit data for all major highways, but also alerts by flashing the current speed indicator in red when the limit is exceeded.

Answer (score 1):

### [Waze Navigation & Live Traffic](https://apps.apple.com/app/waze/id323229106)

[Waze](https://waze.com) (official website) is a free app that guides you through your journey, giving you insights into traffic, construction, police, accidents and more. It also has a speed limit feature.

[image: iPhone screenshots from https://apps.apple.com/app/waze/id323229106 (Waze on the App Store)]